# symfony console doctrine:database:create - fails

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, mysql-connector

I am trying to create a DB with symfony doctrine and MySQL after running:

```
symfony console doctrine:database:create
```

it returns:

```
Could not create database "app" for connection named default
An exception occurred in the driver: could not find driver
```

I have tried the following still to no avail:

```
composer require doctrine/doctrine-bundle
composer require doctrine/orm
composer require symfony/orm-pack
composer require symfony/doctrine-bridge
composer require symfony/maker-bundle
apt-get install php-mysql php-pdo
```

I am running
Symfony CLI version 5.7.5 (c) 2021-2023 Fabien Potencier (2023-12-07T15:46:32Z - stable)

PHP 8.2.13 (cli)

Server version: 8.0.35-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 (Ubuntu)

linux 5.15.0-91-generic

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://app:!ChangeMe!@127.0.0.1:3306/app?serverVersion=8&charset=utf8mb4"
```

Comment: Can you post a redacted version of the DSN you are trying?

Comment: Have a look in your .env file in the symfony root directory, it will be the DATABASE_URL, that needs to be setup with your sql login credentials.

Comment: Per the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#configuring-the-database), in your `.env` or equivalent should be a constant called `DATABASE_URL`.

Comment: appended thank you for your help..

Comment: Check your PHP Info, see if you have a MySQL PDO driver. You might need to enable it in your php.ini file.

Comment: I un commented it in the php.ini as well as see it listed.. wondering if it’s a version issue

Comment: You probably have two versions of php , cli version and webserver version. For symfony command line it's going to need cli version. Can you add the output of `php -m `